# Why am I not able to get the email of the author in Azure Devops Commits API?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I have the API Endpoint as -
`https://dev.azure.com/{{organization}}/{{ProjectName}}/_apis/git/repositories/{{RepositoryId}}/commits?api-version=6.1-preview.1`

Here I'm not able to get the email of the author, it has the value of null.

```
"author": {
                "name": "Name",
                "email": null,
                "date": "2021-04-14T11:44:36Z"
            }
```

Comment: When you view this commit in the git console (with `git log`, for instance) - does it display the email of the commit author?

Comment: Edit: Solved it, by adding a different api key in postman, earlier it was inheriting authorization from the parent folder, with the correct scopes, I got the email. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you try with this API link and edit Fabrikam and Norman with your credential :

`GET https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/commits?searchCriteria.author=Norman Paulk&api-version=6.0`

Reference for above suggestion is here : [Commits - Get Commits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/commits/get%20commits?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#by-author)